# Upload a file using Java program to server- server response gives Content-Length=0

Tags: java, php

I am trying to upload a file to a server. I have write the client code in java. Server code is written in php.
I am getting  Content-Length=0 in server response. But when I upload a file using chrome rest client it gives the content length. Here is my java client code:

```
private String FileUploading(String url1) throws Exception
{
    int bytesRead, bytesAvailable, bufferSize;
    byte[] buffer;
    int maxBufferSize = 1*1024*1024;
    FileInputStream fileInputStream=null;
    HttpsURLConnection connection=null;
    DataOutputStream dos = null;
    FileInputStream fileInputStream=null;
    HttpsURLConnection connection=null;
    DataOutputStream dos = null;
    try{
        File fl=new File("D://abc.txt");
        fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(fl);
        url = new URL(url1);
        connection = (HttpsURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        connection.setReadTimeout(15*1000);
        connection.setRequestProperty ("Authorization", "aaa " + "abc123ss556");
        connection.setRequestProperty ("date_param", "123456");
        connection.setRequestProperty ("userid", "aaa");
        connection.setRequestProperty ("pwd", "111");
        connection.setRequestProperty("Connection", "Keep-Alive");
        connection.setRequestProperty("ENCTYPE", "multipart/form-data");
        connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data;boundary=" + boundary);
        connection.setRequestProperty("uploaded_file", fl.getName());
        String contentDisposition = "Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"userfile\"; filename=\"" + fl.getName() + "\"";
        connection.setRequestProperty ("Content-Disposition", contentDisposition);
        connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
        connection.setUseCaches(false);
        connection.setDoInput(true);
        connection.setDoOutput(true);
        connection.connect();
        dos = new DataOutputStream(connection.getOutputStream());
        int responseCode = connection.getResponseCode();
        int responseCode = connection.getResponseCode();
        dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + lineEnd);
        dos.writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"uploaded_file\";filename=\"" + fl.getName() + "\"" + lineEnd);
        dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);
        bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
        buffer = new byte[bufferSize];
        bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize); 
        while (bytesRead > 0) {
            dos.write(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
            bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
            bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);  
        }
        dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);
        dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + twoHyphens + lineEnd);
        int serverResponseCode = connection.getResponseCode();
        System.out.println(serverResponseCode);
        String serverResponseMessage = connection.getResponseMessage();
        System.out.println(serverResponseMessage);
        fileInputStream.close();
        dos.flush();
        dos.close();
    } catch (MalformedURLException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException ioe) {
        ioe.printStackTrace();
    } catch(Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
//------------------ read the SERVER RESPONSE
    try {
        inStream = new DataInputStream ( connection.getInputStream() );
        String str;
        while (( str = inStream.readLine()) != null)
        {
            System.out.println("Server Response "+str);
        }
        inStream.close();

    }catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
return null;
}
```

}

Comment: in server response it gives: [Content-Length] => 0  please suggest to solve the issue.

Comment: now it show the content length but file are not showing on server side.